# Existence of Symmetric Pure Strategy Equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have 2 symmetric players $A$ and $B$.

Each of them has 2 decision variables $x_i\in[0, \beta]$ and $y_i\in[0,1]$, where $i\in\{A,B\}$.

Their payoff functions are symmetric, i.e., if you swap the label $A$ and $B$, you get the other player's payoff function. And the payoff function is continuous in both $x$ and $y$.

My question is: for this type of game, does it always have symmetric pure strategy equilibrium? In general, what are the conditions to guarantee the existence of symmetric pure strategy equilibrium?

Comment: In general it does not even have a pure strategy equilibrium. I believe there are some results of existence of such equilibrium in supermodular games.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no guarantee that symmetric games have symmetric equilibria.
   See [this paper](https://www.rochester.edu/college/faculty/markfey/papers/SymmGame3.pdf) for concrete examples.
2. There is also no guarantee that symmetric games have pure-strategy equilibria. For example,  the following game is symmetric and has no pure-strategy equilibria 
   $$
   \begin{array}{cccc}
   & \mathrm{a} & \mathrm{b} & \mathrm{c}\\
   \mathrm{a} & 1,1 & 0,2 & 5,0\\
   \mathrm{b} & 2,0 & 3,3 & 0,4\\
   \mathrm{c} & 0,5 & 4,0 & 1,1\\
   \end{array}
   $$
3. There are two special kinds of games that are known to always have pure strategy equilibria: [supermodular games](https://web.stanford.edu/~jdlevin/Econ%20286/Supermodular%20Games.pdf) and [potential games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_game).

Comment: The first has a symmetric equilibrium. Just not in pure strategies.

Comment: Thank you, I will change the example.